# Exporting to WebGL

Tags: export, webgl

I want to create models for website and interact with it. I chose Blender since it is open source. My intention is to create some model, say a table and export to webGL. How can I export the model using Blender in order to view it in a webpage? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Blender prior to version 2.6 you can use the Blender [WebGL exporter](https://code.google.com/p/blender-webgl-exporter/) wich exports to json..It supports native WebGL. Looks like the script is no longer maintained..

I think you should also have success with formats like obj, collada or md2.

Comment: The link says the script will not work for 2.6+. (https://code.google.com/p/blender-webgl-exporter/wiki/InstallScript) Have you used this for v2.74?

Comment: @Kaushik I see, the scripts is no longer maintained .. I looked into it and the is too much to repair to work in 2.6+.. Does your model use something specific to v.2.6+? Otherwise you should be able to export from older blender..

Comment: I am not specific about versions, want to give it a try.